# How to output the results of 100 trials to a text file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to output the results of an `array` of 100 trials to an output `file` and am having trouble with the syntax.

The finished program should be able to:

1. Read in each trial into a hundred element array
2. Calculate the mean for that trial
3. Determine the median for that trial
4. Determine the minimum value for that trial
5. Determine the maximum value for that trial
6. Calculate the standard deviation for that trial
7. Print out the results of each trial to an output file

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// Declare global constants
const char *IN_FILE_NAME = "stats.txt";
const char *OUT_FILE_NAME = "results.txt";
const int ELEMENTS = 100;

// Function Prototypes
bool getTrialElements (ifstream &, double[], int);
void sortElements (double[], int);
double findMean (double[], int);
double findMedian (double[], int);
double findMinimum (double[], int);
double findMaximum (double[], int);
double findStdDev (double[], int);
void printTrialResults (ofstream &, int, double[], int);

// This program performs basic statistics on a large set of data points
int main ()
{
    // Declare variables
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    int trialNumber = 0;
    double elementArray[ELEMENTS];

    // Open input and output files
    inFile.open (IN_FILE_NAME);
    outFile.open (OUT_FILE_NAME);

    // Loop through all of the data sets in the input file
    while (getTrialElements (inFile, elementArray, ELEMENTS)) {
        // Keep track of the number of data sets processed
        trialNumber++;
        // Output the results to the output file
        printTrialResults (outFile, trialNumber, elementArray, ELEMENTS);
    }

    // Close input and output files
    outFile.close ();
    inFile.close ();

    return 0;
}

bool getTrialElements (ifstream & fin, double array[], int size)
{
    int i;
    //Read 100 elements, or till the end of file.
    for (i = 0; i < 100 && !fin.eof (); i++)
        fin >> array[i];
    if (i != 100)       // If the trial doesn't contain 100 elements 
        return false;   // (it could be even no elements.)
    return true;        // Return true otherwise.
}

//Sorts elements in increasing order
void sortElements (double array[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
            if (array[j] < array[j + 1]) {
                double temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
} 

//Finds the mean of each trial
double findMean (double array[], int size)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sum += array[i];
    return sum / size;
}

//Finds the Median of each trial
double findMedian (double array[], int size)
{
    sortElements (array, size);
    if (size % 2 == 0)
        return (array[size / 2] + array[size / 2 - 1]) / 2.0;
    return array[size / 2];
}

//Finds the smallest value in each trial 
double findMinimum (double array[], int size)
{
    double min = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        if (array[i] < min)
            min = array[i];
    return min;
}

//Finds the largest value in each trial 
double findMaximum (double array[], int size)
{
    double max = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        if (array[i] > max)
            max = array[i];
    return max;
}

//Calculates the standard deviation of each trial 
double findStdDev (double array[], int size)
{
    double stdDev = 0;
    double avg = findMean (array, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        stdDev += pow (array[i] - avg, 2);
    stdDev = sqrt (1 / (double) size * stdDev);
    return stdDev;
}

//outputs results trial by trial
void printTrialResults (ofstream &, int trialNumber, double array[], int size)
{
    ofstream out_data ("results.txt");
    out_data << "trial " << setw (5) << left << trialNumber++;
    out_data << "mean: " << setw (6) << left << fixed << setprecision (1)
    << findMean (array, size);
    out_data << "median: " << setw (6) << left << fixed <<
        setprecision (1) << findMedian (array, size);
    out_data << "min: " << setw (6) << left << fixed << setprecision (1)
    << findMinimum (array, size);
    out_data << "max: " << setw (6) << left << fixed << setprecision (1)
    << findMaximum (array, size);
    out_data << "std dev: " << setw (6) << left << fixed <<
        setprecision (1)
    << findStdDev (array, size);
    cout << endl;
}
```

The result is only outputting trial #1 but I need all results output to a text file.

Comment: Still, I see that the name of the outfile is used in two places, which indicates an error of thought. printTrialstuff ignores its first argument, the open outfile, and instead outputs using a local stream, which is automatically closed when the function returns.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this line here

```
ofstream out_data("results.txt");
```

You call it every time you want to print out a new trial. Every time you declare that variable it will write over the file which is why you are only getting the last trial in your output file. The best solution is to probably pass it by reference to the function to avoid declaring it more than once.